IDEA maven project doesn't show up when searching for dependencies?
See Picture 1 for mine. The desired effect is Picture 2. I'm not getting results for anything I'm searching for.



This functionality is handled by the Package Search Plugin (https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12507-package-search) make sure you have the latest version, try re-installing the Plugin.
